# Run Code Coverage report on a NPM artifact in azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run the npm code-coverage task over a npm artifact (zip file) without having to rebuild the entire package again. i.e. consume a npm artifact and run code-coverage task over it.

Is this possible?

Comment: @ Abhineet Chaudhary, 
Do you mean that you want to run the code coverage for the source code of the npm package?

What the npm code-coverage task is? I do not find this task on the [Marketplace for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops). Could you please share the link of this task on the Marketplace?

If possible, please share more details about your use case.

Comment: Hi @Abhineet Chaudhary, I have not heard from you for a few of days. Just want to say Hi and check if there is anything I can help. How are things going? Please share more details about your question. I am looking forward for your response.